# Why are my creases horizontal instead of vertical in the sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting

Whenever I try to sculpt creases (I am modelling a couch), they come out horizontal instead of vertical, no matter in which direction I drag the cursor. I also tried switching sculpt planes. I would really appreciate an answer, since it's sort of urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess would be that you don't have enough geometry in your couch. If all of your polygons are long, thin, horizontal polys, then that's going to affect the way it looks.

There are two ways to solve this problem. One is to manually add more geometry. You want the density the polygons to be the same across the whole couch, and you want them to all be as square as possible. Insert Edge Loops (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) will probably be very helpful if you decide to try this approach.

The other solution is to use Dynamic Topology. This will dynamically add geometry as needed, but it will still have an easier time if your geometry is even and consistent.

From [the Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/painting_sculpting/sculpting/adaptive.html):

> Dynamic topology (AKA dyntopo) is a dynamic tessellation sculpting method, adds and removes details on the fly. Dyntopo is quick, just get a brush and start to sculpt. Dyntopo will add details base upon your brush size, detail type and strength.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer:) I guessed this might be a problem too. I had many horizontal edge loops, and practically no vertical. However, I have applied a subsurf modifier, and after that I tried to sculpt. Do you think this might be a problem? I also thought I could use remesh modifier, but my knowldge about sculpting is poorer than just poor:) I will definitely try to use Dyntopo:)

Comment: Adding edge loops really helped. Dyntopo makes my laptop work slower than a snail, so I used the first method. Thanks again for your kind advice:)

Comment: You're welcome! Applying the subsurf modifier would neither have solved nor caused the problem. The subsurf would have just subdivided the long thin polys into smaller, long thin polys ;-) I'm glad you got it working!